# Facing GCC installation issue while setting up airflow on hadoop cluster

Tags: linux, hadoop, airflow

I have set up a three nodes Hadoop cluster for dev environment wherein one act as a master 
node and other being as a datanodes.
cluster has been set up with below configurations/version:

```
Operating System: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.7
python 3.7.3
anaconda 2
spark 2.45
```

I would like to install and configure airflow with mysql as a backend database on this hadoop cluster set up. I thought of asking something else regarding configuring MySQL as a backend database but receiving an error while running pip on master node itself.

```
    pip install apache-airflow
```

**Error Message:**

```
      Running setup.py install for setproctitle ... error
        ERROR: Complete output from command /root/anaconda2/bin/python -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-TUrT4x/setproctitle/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-GdyZzq/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
        ERROR: running install
        running build
        running build_ext
        building 'setproctitle' extension
        creating build
        creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
        creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src
        gcc -pthread -B /root/anaconda2/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DHAVE_SYS_PRCTL_H=1 -DSPT_VERSION=1.1.10 -I/root/anaconda2/include/python2.7 -c src/setproctitle.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/setproctitle.o
        unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory
        error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
        ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Command "/root/anaconda2/bin/python -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-TUrT4x/setproctitle/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-GdyZzq/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-TUrT4x/setproctitle/
```

when I typed `which gcc`, I get this.

```
which gcc

    /usr/bin/which: no gcc in (/home/xyz/anaconda2/envs/python3.7.2/bin:/home/xyz/anaconda2/bin:/home/xyz/spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:
    /usr/sbin:/home/xyz/jdk1.8.0_241/bin:/home/xyz/hadoop-2.7.7/bin:/home/xyz/.local/bin:/home/xyz/bin)
```

`'xyz'` is user name

I am looking for some help to solve above issue and suggestion regarding airflow for the above mentioned configurations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gcc` is a pre-requisite for Apache Airflow and it looks like it is not installed.

You can install it using this command,

```
sudo yum install gcc gcc-c++ -y
```

You might need these development packages as well,

```
sudo yum install libffi-devel mariadb-devel cyrus-sasl-devel -y
```

Comment: Do you have any reference or good link available to set up the whole airflow process?

Comment: Try [this](https://medium.com/@0x0ece/installing-apache-airflow-on-centos-7-750c77b7aa35) for pre-requisites. For the actual setup, it will take you to the Airflow documentation.

Comment: I am getting below error when I run airflow initdb command. Let me know if I need to post another question with other details. "ImportError: /home/xyz/anaconda2/envs/python3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_mysql.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: symbol mysql_real_escape_string_quote, version libmysqlclient_18 not defined in file libmysqlclient.so.18 with link time reference"

Comment: Yes please create a new question.